# LibreOffice version

Tags: 12.04, software-center, libreoffice

Now, I use LibreOffice Writer 3.5.7.2 . According to http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/34088/selecting-copying-pasting-text/ and further things I need LibreOffice Writer 4.0 or higher. When it may be in the Ubuntu Software Center for my Ubuntu 12.04? If it is there, is it offered by my Upgrade Manager without my  request? Thanks.

Comment: you have to add `libreoffice-4-2` PPA.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps to upgrade to the latest stable LibreOffice 4.2 version on Ubuntu Precise.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-2

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

The repository [ppa:libreoffice/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) no longer supports packages for 12.04. As the other posts point out (see the link in the above comments to an earlier post), this ppa will not work for versions later than 4.2.